# I have made an istance of TvShow , but when I want to create it in my local database, NullPointerException error in my readFromApi2 method

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, hibernate

Here I have created a new object TvShow tvShow = new TvShow(id, name, genresList, rating, 60, 54, summary, "Link");
and then   tvShowController.createTvShow(tvShow);
The error is Can not resolve symbol tvShowController.

I have added the whole hirarki of my classes, so it would be easier to find my mistake.

```
 package com.example.payex;


    import com.sun.tools.javac.Main;
    import org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Autowired;
    import org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication;
    import org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.SpringBootApplication;

    import javax.net.ssl.HttpsURLConnection;
    import java.net.URL;
    import java.util.ArrayList;
    import java.util.List;
    import java.util.Scanner;

    import com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.JsonNode;
    import com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.ObjectMapper;

    import org.json.simple.JSONArray;
   import org.json.simple.JSONObject;
   import org.json.simple.parser.JSONParser;
   import org.json.simple.parser.ParseException;
   import com.example.payex.Genres;

    @SpringBootApplication
    public class PayExApplication {


    public static void main(String[] args) {

        SpringApplication.run(PayExApplication.class, args);
        TvShowController tvShowController = new TvShowController();
        readFromApi2();

    }


    public static void readFromApi2() {
        ObjectMapper objectMapper = new ObjectMapper();

        List<Genres> genresList = new ArrayList<>();
        try {
            URL url = new URL("https://api.tvmaze.com/singlesearch/shows?q=breaking%20bad");
            HttpsURLConnection connection = (HttpsURLConnection) url.openConnection();
            connection.setRequestMethod("GET");
            connection.connect();

            int responseCode = connection.getResponseCode();

            if (responseCode != 200) {
                throw new RuntimeException("Http Response" + responseCode);
            } else {
                JSONParser jsonParser = new JSONParser();
                StringBuilder infoString = new StringBuilder();
                Scanner scanner = new Scanner(url.openStream());
                while (scanner.hasNext()) {
                    infoString.append(scanner.nextLine());
                }
                scanner.close();
                JsonNode jsonNode = objectMapper.readTree(String.valueOf(infoString));
                JSONObject jsonObject = (JSONObject) 
                jsonParser.parse(String.valueOf(infoString));
                JSONArray jsonArray = (JSONArray) jsonObject.get("genres");


                int id = jsonNode.get("id").asInt();
                String name = jsonNode.get("name").asText();

                Double rating = jsonNode.get("rating").get("average").asDouble();
                String summary = jsonNode.get("summary").asText();

                genresList.add(Genres.ACTION);
                genresList.add(Genres.ADVENTURE);
                genresList.add(Genres.ESPOINAGE);

                TvShow tvShow = new TvShow(id, name, genresList, rating, 60, 54, summary, "Link");

                tvShowController.createTvShow(tvShow);
            }
        } catch (Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
}
    package com.example.payex;

    import org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Autowired;
    import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.*;

    import java.util.ArrayList;
    import java.util.List;

    @RestController
    @CrossOrigin
    public class TvShowController {

    @Autowired
    TvShowService tvShowService ;


    @GetMapping("/getAllTvShow")
    public List<TvShow> getAllTvShow(){

        return tvShowService.getListOfAllTvShow() ;
    }
    @PostMapping("/createTvShow")
    public void createTvShow(@RequestBody TvShow tvShow){
        System.out.println("hei" + tvShow.getRating());
        tvShowService.createTvShow(tvShow) ;
    }

   @DeleteMapping("/deleteTvShow/{id}")
    public void deleteTvShow(@PathVariable long id){
        TvShow tvShow = tvShowService.findById(id) ;
        if(tvShow!=null)
            tvShowService.deleteTvShow(tvShow);
    }

}

    package com.example.payex;

    import org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Autowired;
    import org.springframework.stereotype.Service;

    import java.util.List;

    @Service
    public class TvShowService {

    @Autowired
    TvShowRepository tvShowRepository ;

    public TvShow createTvShow(TvShow tvShow){
        System.out.println("God dag");
        System.out.println(tvShow.toString());
        return tvShowRepository.save(tvShow) ;
    }
    public void deleteTvShow(TvShow tvShow){
        tvShowRepository.delete(tvShow);
    }
    public List<TvShow> getListOfAllTvShow(){
        return (List<TvShow>) tvShowRepository.findAll();
    }
    public TvShow findById(long id){
        return tvShowRepository.findById(id).orElse(null);
    }


}
```

Comment: Adding *all* your code doesn't make it easier. You can make it easier by making a MCVE, reduce the problem to the smallest bit of code that reproduces the problem. The nice thing is, you often find the problem by yourself while doing that!

Comment: tvShowController is a local variable in your main method. It doesn't exist outside of it